# The code is running through all loops despite if statements

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm using ejs. No matter what my statement returns(no matter what `currentGame` is), my output is always 12. I've tried implementing `break;` or `return;` and tried using other loops like `switch case` or `while`, but it didn't help.
If I make `console.log` in each loop, I get {1, 2, 3...12} as output.

```js
"<%var x%>"

  "<%for(var i=1; i<=12; i++){%>"
  if(currentGame === "<%=i%>"){
      "<%x=i;%>"
  }

"<%}%>"
console.log("<%=x%>")
```

And the resulting code I get in my browser is:

```
        ""

  ""
  if(currentGame === "1"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "2"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "3"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "4"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "5"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "6"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "7"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "8"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "9"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "10"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "11"){
      ""
  }

""
  if(currentGame === "12"){
      ""
  }

""
console.log("12")
```

Comment: Please show the **resulting code** you get in the browser. Based on the above, I'd expect it's a series of `if(currentGame === "1"){}` and `if(currentGame === "2"){}` etc. all the way through 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code is assigning to your server-side `x` variable **unconditionally**, here:

```
"<%var x%>"

"<%for(var i=1; i<=12; i++){%>"
if(currentGame === "<%=i%>"){
    "<%x=i;%>" // <===================================
}

"<%}%>"
console.log("<%=x%>")
```

The `if` is **client-side** code, it doesn't have any effect on the server-side logic. The server-side logic in that code looks like this:

```
var x

for(var i=1; i<=12; i++){
    x=i;
}
```

Which is the problem. `x` will always be 12.

---

Stepping back, though, from the specific code you've posted: Using server-side code to generate client-side code is almost never a good idea. Instead, write your client code and your server code separately, so this kind of confusion doesn't arise.